# Partial sum of Fourier series of square wave

Tags: fourier-series, trigonometric-series

> Let $f$ be a $2π$ -periodic square wave function so that
>   $$f\, = -1 \quad -π \le x<0$$ 
>   $$f=1   \qquad   0 \le x< π$$
>   $S_{2n-1}(x)$ is the $(2n-1)st$ Fourier polynomial of $f$. Prove that it can be written as:
>   $$S_{2n-1}(x)=\frac{1}{nπ}\int_0^{2nx} \frac{\sin t } {\sin {\frac {t} {2n}}} 
> dt$$

It's obvious that the Fourier-Series can be written as:
$$F_N(x)=\frac {4}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\sin((2n-1)x)}{2n-1}$$
But thats as much as I can do about it.
Can someone explain the ongoing to me further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to notice that:
$$\frac{\sin((2n-1)x)}{(2n-1)}=\int_{0}^{x}\cos((2n-1)u)\,du $$
hence:
$$ F_N(x) = \frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{x}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\cos((2n-1)u)\,du =\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin(2Nu)}{\sin u}\,du=\frac{1}{\pi N}\int_{0}^{2N x}\frac{\sin t}{\sin\frac{t}{2N}}\,dt.$$
For the middle equality, see [this classical question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro).